# Can you pass instance metadata to a web application

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am new to aws, so this is going to be worded badly. I am wondering if I can get the metadata of the instance and pass it to my web application. I am using a ec2 and a s3 bucket to hold the web application folder.

Comment: What do you mean by metadata here? You can certainly use the AWS APIs programmatically to describe AWS infrastructure and retrieve data (such as an EC2 instance's ID, its tags, etc.) From within an EC2 instance you can also [retrieve local EC2 metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html).

Comment: Thanks, could you give an example of how you'd do this or a way to learn more about it. I've been searching on google, but I don't know enough to search for what I want. I've tried looking up stuff like "use AWS API instance metadata" but all I get is how to view it in the cli.

Comment: The link I pointed you to shows you how to retrieve instance metadata from within an EC2 instance. Use your programming SDK or tool of choice to fetch it from the metadata service. If you want to more generally retrieve EC2 metadata then use an AWS SDK (or the awscli) to make requests to the EC2 service APIs (example for Python [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html)).

Comment: Is there just an api that I can call that will return the ec2 metadata so that I can insert it into my html?

Comment: Within an EC2 instance, the metadata is available via HTTP GET request to `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/` (for IMDSv1). It's not an API per se. Use your preferred HTTP client and send an HTTP request to that URL. Try it out from the shell on your EC2 instance using curl.

Comment: Sorry, I mean like from in my js code inside my web application. I'd like to be able to display the ipv4 address as text on the website.

Comment: You know how to make HTTP calls from your Node.js webapp, I'm assuming. Use your preferred HTTP client (axios, fetch, requests, etc.) Or find a library that abstracts it, for example [node-ec2-metadata](https://github.com/davidtucker/node-ec2-metadata).

Comment: So I just do a noraml fetch() but with http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/?